# Stored procedure "forgetting" field between update and insert statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure that is used to `UPDATE` a table with a value calculated from an existing column.

I am trying to amend the stored procedure to also `INSERT` a row into a different table, using that same column's value but the column is being rejected by the parser as an invalid column name.

Here is a condensed version of the code. As originally supplied the `sequence_no` is known to the stored procedure and ends up in `reference_no`. i.e. the `UPDATE` works but the `INSERT` fails.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_references]
AS
    -- Original contents:
    UPDATE table1
    SET reference_no = sequence_no
    FROM table1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN proptable p1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON t1.checkval = p1.checkval
    WHERE p1.fruit = 'apple'

    -- I have added the INSERT 
    INSERT INTO table2 (next_seq_no)
    VALUES (sequence_no)
```

The `sequence_no` is underlined in red in SSMS.

Comment: Its underlined because sequence_no is not a column name.  I assume It is a variable since you said it was passed in.  so it shoule be @sequence_no.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but do you have a good reason for using `NOLOCK`? It can (and will) cause you're query to provide wrong results.

Comment: you absolutely should not use NOLOCK on an UPDATE target. It is deprecated, has caused corruption, and SQL Server will still take locks anyway https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Comment: @JMabee looks like sequence_no belongs to proptable to me

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree - `sequence_no` is a column name in the `proptable` most likely. Since it is a column, and not a value, the value will not be "in memory", and cannot be referenced in a second insert.

Comment: Another potential gotcha with your code here. You have a left join to proptable but then you have a where predicate that only returns those rows who has a value of apple for fruit. That has essentially turned your left join into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

The insert statement in your code knows nothing about the previous update so you can't reference random columns from that and expect them to still be in scope. The easiest way of doing this is using the `OUTPUT` clause.

```
UPDATE table1
SET reference_no = sequence_no
OUTPUT INSERTED.reference_no INTO table2 (next_seq_no)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN proptable p1 ON t1.checkval = p1.checkval
WHERE p1.fruit = 'apple'
```